# Deriving the posterior distribution parameters of a normal distribution in the context of dereverberation

Tags: speech-processing, optimization, probability-distribution-function

Context:
$\bar{\Theta}$ is the room regression filter coefficients (RRC);
$$X_{t} = \bar{\Theta}^{H}\bar{X}_{t-1} + s_{t}$$ means in words: the filter that defines how the room causes reverberation to the signal (how the past of the speech signal x affects the current speech signal).
$s$ is drawn from $\mathcal{N}(0,\lambda_{t}).$
The goal of this analysis is to find the most likely $\bar{\Theta}$ with $\eqref{1}$ being the likelihood function.

I’m trying to get from these three expressions:

\begin{align}
\mathcal{P}(\Theta | \bar{X}_{t}) &= \dfrac{\mathcal{P}(X_t|\Theta,\bar{X}_{t-1})\mathcal{P}(\Theta|\bar{X}_{t-1})}{\int{\mathcal{P}(X_{t}|\Theta,\bar{X}_{t-1})\mathcal{P}(\Theta|\bar{X}_{t-1})}}&&\text{due to Bayes}\tag{1}\label{1}\\
\mathcal{P}(X_{t}|\Theta,\bar{X}_{t-1}) &= \mathcal{N}(x_{t};\bar{\Theta}^H\bar{X}_{t-1},\lambda_{t})\tag{2}\label{2}\\
\mathcal{P}(\Theta|\bar{X}_{t-1}) &= \mathcal{N}(\bar{\Theta};\bar{\mu}_{t-1},\Phi_{t-1})\tag{3}\label{3}
\end{align}

To the following expressions describing $\mathcal{P}(\Theta|\bar{X}_{t})$:

\begin{align}
\mathcal{P}\left(\Theta|\bar{X}_{t}\right) &= \mathcal{N}\left(\bar{\Theta};\bar{\mu}_{t},\Phi_{t}\right)&\text{ with}\tag{4}\label{4}\\
\mu_{t} &= \Phi_{t}\left(\frac{\bar{X}_{t-1}X_{t}^{*}}{\lambda_{t}} + \Phi_{t-1}^{-1}\bar{\mu}_{t-1}\right)\tag{5}\label{5}\\
\Phi_{t} &= \left(\dfrac{\bar{X}_{t-1}X_{t-1}^{H}}{\lambda_{t-1}} + \Phi_{t-1}^{-1}\right)^{-1}\tag{6}\label{6}
\end{align}

Things I tried: I think the denominator in $\eqref{1}$ is always 1 so there is no need to calculate that integral. I didn’t really get anywhere by just substituting the appropriate terms in $\eqref{1}$ with $\eqref{2}$ and $\eqref{3}$, so I thought since the goal is to find the most likely $\Theta$, $\eqref{5}$ & $\eqref{6}$ are the solution of the optimization problem, $\arg\max\limits_{\mu_{t-1},\Phi_{t-1}} \eqref{1}$.

Perhaps these expressions were derived from the appropriate gradients, and I got a similar expression for $\mu$ (not the same expression though) and nothing close with $\Phi$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with this notation. Are the RRC anything different than the room impulse response ? It also looks like you noise is white, which really isn't a good model for acoustic noise (which is typically pink or even brown).

Comment: Hi, regarding s, this models the original (not reverberated) speech signal, not additive noise, but maybe that's what you meant, I'm not sure. anyways considering that meaning for s, I think the RRC  differs from the room impulse response, the room impulse response would have s go through it to receive x_t

Answer (score 0):

The derivation is exactly the same as the derivation for the Kalman Filter.

Basically you're after the conditional of 2 random Gaussian vectors:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, and sorry if I missed your point, but I didn't quite get how do you map x and y here to the question. if you meant x=theta and y=x_t (vector) than I'll say that the parameters of their distributions aren't known, so known x|y in the terms of these parameters doesn't solve the problem. and again thanks for the answer

Comment: @user3371266, They are known as a parameter. Like I posted.

Comment: the known parameters belong to the variables (Xt|Θ,X¯t−1) and (Θ|X¯t−1) but not Theta and X_t themselves but perhaps taking x = Θ|X¯t−1 and y=Xt|Θ,X¯t−1 works, I will check. is this really the mapping you used?

Comment: It is the same concept, assuming Gaussian Variables in the context of conditional Gaussian Variables.

Comment: same concept as what? can you state the mapping you used from x and y to the question's variable, to receive (4) (5) and (6) from (1) (2) (3)?

Comment: @user3371266, Do you know how to derive the the moments of a Gaussian Random Vector conditioned on another? Your question boils to that. What I gave you is the general derivation.